# How to pass looping value attribute from the <options> tag to onchange attribute in the <select> tag

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using the laravel framework. I populated my dropdown list with data from my database.

```
<select class="form-control" id="username" name="username" onchange="somerandonfunction(blah)">     
            <option value="" selected>Select User</option>
            @foreach($getUsers as $list)
            <option value="{{$list->id}}" >{{$list->name}}</option>
            @endforeach

        </select>
```

I want to be able to pass the value of the option clicked to a function in the onchange attribute in the select> tag. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This again.....

Answer (score 0):

You can pass this.value in function

```
<select class="form-control" id="username" name="username" onchange="somerandonfunction(this.value)">     
        <option value="" selected>Select User</option>
        @foreach($getUsers as $list)
        <option value="{{$list->id}}" >{{$list->name}}</option>
        @endforeach

    </select>
```